# Add label to input

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have an input (type="file") for uploading files.

```
<div className="upload-image">
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      onChange={this.toSomething()}
      type="file"
      className="imgr"
    />
    <span className="upload-image-label">
      <Icon name="image outline" />
      Drag & drop image or click here
    </span>
  </div>
```

I want to add a label above the input part so I add it inside input:

```
<div className="upload-image">
    <input
      accept="image/*"
      label="Add Image" // this line was added
      onChange={this.toSomething()}
      type="file"
      className="imgr"
    />
    <span className="upload-image-label">
      <Icon name="image outline" />
      Drop image here
    </span>
  </div>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear. What is wrong?

Comment: for inputs label is a tag, not an attribute

Answer (score 0):

As px1mp said, in HTML5, `label` is a tag, not an attribute. Check out [the Mozilla team documentation about labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Label).

You can achieve what you are looking for by doing something like that:

```
<div className="upload-image">
    <label for="image-input">Add image</label>
    <input
      name="image"
      id="image-input"
      accept="image/*"
      onChange={this.toSomething()}
      type="file"
      className="imgr"
    />
    <span className="upload-image-label">
      <Icon name="image outline" />
      Drop image here
    </span>
  </div>
```